# smooth effect when auto scrolling to anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, autoscroll

I use the below code to make auto scrolling to anchor

```
        setTimeout(function(){window.location.hash = "#anchor";},5000);
```

It's working fine, but I need to add a smooth effect when it scroll.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HZejZ/)

Comment: Hello user3083292, I need more info. What exactly you want??

Comment: Give the exact details you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common solution using jQuery is to animate the `scrollTop` property to the offset y-position of the target element:

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#anchor').offset().top
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HZejZ/1/

You might be able to listen to the `hashchange` event if you want to keep your code as it is (untested):

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $target = $(window.location.hash);
    if ( $target.length ) {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $target.offset().top});
    }
});
```

(edit: this seems to be problematic, the browser will jump even if preventDefault is called)

Comment: nice and simple

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```
  $('html, #anchor').animate({ scrollTop: 0 },'slow');
```

It is 100% working code. If it is also working for you then please mark it as an answer so that others can also use it...

Comment: user3083292, Please like this as answer so that other can use it from your post as an reference